# Pass up a value from a child to parent and then to parent's parent (React.js)

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty good with passing a value up to parent from a child by using triggers.

But say I have grand-parent component that displays items.
Inside item I have an overlay with a button that launches a modal with adding another item inside, like this:

- Layer 1: Item display /has a parameter in a state whether show modal or not. By default it's not/
- Layer 2: Item
- Layer 3: overlay over item with add-item button.

I want my add-item button from so-called layer 3 to cause changes in layer 1, changing show-modal parameter to true.

What should I do here, use application state-managment? Is there a method without application state-management implementation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create function which changes state in L1 and pass it all the way down to L3 which will invoke it when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Layer1 = React.createComponent({
    updateState(value) {
        return this.setState({value: value});
    },

    render() {
        return <Layer2 onClick={this.updateState}/>;
    }

});

Layer2 = React.createComponent({

    render() {
        return <Layer3 onClick={this.props.onClick}/>;
    }

});

Layer3 = React.createComponent({

    handleClick() {
        return this.props.onClick('new value sending up!');
    },

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick}/>;
    }

});
```